# Build MYSQL Search query to search comma-separate string with in another comma-separate string

Tags: mysql

I want to build a MySQL query to search comma-separate string with in another comma-separate string.

The sub-string will always be from the original string with different orders (comma separated). Below are the few example.

Original String : 1,2,3,4,5,6

a. 1,2,4,6

b. 4,6,1

c. 2,3

What will be the MySQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REPLACE` and `REGEXP` for that:

```
SELECT t.string FROM my_table t WHERE t.string REGEXP REPLACE('1,2,4,6', ',', '|');
SELECT t.string FROM my_table t WHERE t.string REGEXP REPLACE('4,6,1', ',', '|');
SELECT t.string FROM my_table t WHERE t.string REGEXP REPLACE('2,3', ',', '|');
```

All these queries will match `'1,2,3,4,5,6'` value in `t.string` column;

Of course first parameter of `REPLACE()` function in these SQL queries can/should be dynamic comma separated string;